# NServiceBus Azure Queue Transport: Set connection string in code

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus

I'm using NServiceBus with Azure service bus transport. Currently, I provide the connection string for the queue in the app.config like this:

```
<add name="NServiceBus/Transport" connectionString="Endpoint=..." />
```

I need to supply this in code, not in configuration. I'm using the code on [this page](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/custom-configuration-providers) as an example of how to do this, but where they use RijndaelEncryptionServiceConfig as an example, I have no idea what type(s) to use for overriding the transport connection string. To be specific, I have no idea what to put here:

```
    // the part you are overriding
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(RijndaelEncryptionServiceConfig))
    {
        return new RijndaelEncryptionServiceConfig
               {
                   Key = "gdDbqRpqdRbTs3mhdZh9qCaDaxJXl+e6"
               } as T;
    }
```

Can someone guide me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was totally barking up the wrong tree. This works:

```
var busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
busConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>().ConnectionString(@"Endpoint=sb:...");
```

Simple! I was overthinking it.